# Axler 2.5 - linear independence question

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, vectors

I've been trying to solve a question from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* which just doesn't make sense. I assume I've been reading it wrong, and that's why I'd like to present my thoughts about it, in hope someone could point me in the right direction. So the question is:

- Show that if we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then the list $\left(1+i,\:1-i\right)$ is linearly **independent**.
- Show that if we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then the list $\left(1+i,\:1-i\right)$ is linearly **dependent**.

So the first item is pretty obvious, since, if we multiply the given vector by a scalar $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$x\left(1+i,1-i\right)=\left(0,0\right)$$
Then obviously, the only element of $\mathbb{R}$ for which it would be true is $x=0$, which is the trivial solution, thus the list is linearly independent.

Things become perplexing, however, in the second item, in which $x\in C$ and we're supposed to show that the list is linearly **dependent**. But even in $\mathbb{C}$, the only scalar which satisfies the equation: $$x\left(1+i,1-i\right)=\left(0,0\right)$$
is $x=0+0i$, which is still the trivial solution and is not enough to demonstrate that the list is linearly dependent.

I probably have some mistake here, but I honestly can't find it. An explaination would be much appreciated.

Comment: $-i\times (1+i)=1-i$.  More broadly, $\mathbb C$ is one dimensional as a vector space over itself, so there couldn't be two non-zero, linearly independent elements.

Comment: Note:  you appear to be confused as to the definition of "linear dependence".  In the case of two vectors, $\vec u, \vec v$, it means that there exist scalars $a,b$ such that $a\vec u +b\vec v=\vec 0$.  Convince yourself that, if neither vector is itself $\vec 0$, this means that the vectors are multiples of each other.

Comment: The list $(1+i, 1-i)$ is a list of vectors in $C$. That is not a tuple, but rather vectors $$u=(1+i)\text{ and } v=(1-i)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you have some mistakes.

Let $u,v \in \mathbb R$ and $u(1+i)+v(1-i)=0$, then you have to show that $u=v=0.$

Furthermore you have to show that there are $ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$ with $ \alpha \ne 0$ or $ \beta \ne 0$ and $\alpha(1+i)+\beta (1-i)=0$.